# Running a jar in Travis CI

Tags: java, travis-ci

Is it possible to run a jar within Travis? I'm trying to make a custom language work within Travis which I presume should be possible if I'm using a jar interpretor and define the project as a java language.

I have been trying do get it working for a while now and with no success. My latest try looks like this and outputs what's underneath.

```
language: java
install:
  - ls
  - java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar shell-stable.jar src/main.rsc

Version: 0.8.0.201510190912
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/rascalmpl/interpreter/utils/RascalManifest : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.rascalmpl.shell.RascalShell.main(RascalShell.java:36)
The command "java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar shell-stable.jar src/main.rsc" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

That tells Travis to use Java8.

Your error message indicates that your code expects a Java8 environment but it's instead being run in some earlier Java runtime.

If it’s not actually a Java project and all you want to do to is run the jar file, try something like this:

```
language: generic
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java8-set-default
install:
  - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx1G -Xss32m -jar shell-stable.jar src/main.rsc
```

The `addons: apt: packages: oracle-java8-set-default` bit *may* be enough by itself to make Travis use the Java8 `java`—but to ensure Travis does, you can specify the full path to the `java` binary with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java` (assuming you’re building on Linux).

<s>And if you specify the full path to the `java` binary that way, you can probably just omit the `addons: apt: packages: oracle-java8-set-default` part.</s> (Upon further reflection, I guess the `addons: apt: packages: oracle-java8-set-default` part is always needed in this case, to get Travis to actually install Java8 at all.)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was only to make is switchable between versions. Now it tries to run `ant test` but it's not an actual Java project so is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: To tell Travis to not run it as Java project but still be able to run the jar, see my updated answer for a suggestion.